# Softlayer REST API to delete Shared Hardware firewall attached to VM or Baremetal

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I need Softlayer Api to find out which shared firewall my vm/baremetal is using in order to delete it.
Actually I wanted to delete shared hardware firewall service attached to vm. We have generic APIs to delete the resources but when we provision a shared hardware firewall we just get billing id of it since it is just a service(i Think), i found that billing id while cancelling shared hw firewall service from softlayer portal(while inspecting elments). so is there any API to cancel a service or specifically shared hw firewall.

Comment: And your question is?

Answer (score 0):

To know which firewall is attached to your vm, you can use this rest api:

Method: GET

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/[virtualGuestId]/getFirewallServiceComponent
```

Reference:
https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getFirewallServiceComponent/

For the baremetal use the following rest api:

Method: GET

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/[hardwareServerId]/getFirewallServiceComponent
```

Reference:
https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/getFirewallServiceComponent/